# Laravel foreach with order by

Tags: php, laravel

How can i use this foreach with an order by:

```
foreach(Incident::with('domain')->get() as $incident){
```

if I use:

```
foreach(Incident::with('domain')->orderBy('weight')->get() as $incident){
```

It doesn't work. Really hope someone could help me out. Without the orderBy it works but with it it doesn't. I really need the order by.

**UPDATE:**

The problem i'm having is the query that is failing. What i'm trying to accomplish is this. I have 2 laravel model. Incident and Domain. Weight is from Domain. I'm using weight to sort the domains. The incidents are than sorted under a domain by an domain_id by name from incident. Hope this clarifies a lot and someone can help me out.

Comment: What Jonathon Reinhart wanted to say is that we cannot help if we don't have enough information about what's happening. If you just say "it doesn't work" I'll have to guess to understand what's not working and I probably will miss the point since there could be a hundred of possibilities to why this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the foreach that doesn't work, it's probably the query that's not returning what you need, to debug it you can die and dump it by doing:

```
dd( Incident::with('domain')->orderBy('weight')->get() );
```

You should see your records in the order you need them, otherwise you have a problem in your database and/or query.

**EDIT**

If you are getting a 500 error, check your webserver (apache, nginx?) logs to see what is causing it. And, please, show us some error messages.

Comment: If I try this in mozilla I'm still getting the internal 500 server error.

Comment: Still get? Did you told people here about a 500 server error before? Just edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be doing wrong is not passing second parameter to `orderBy()` method.

```
foreach(Incident::with('domain')->orderBy('weight','asc')->get() as $incident){}
```